# How set AdView refresh interval from Java code

Tags: java, android, admob, adview

How programaticaly set interval refresh AdView (com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView) from Java code?

I can use `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(...)` inside `TimerTask`.

But may be exist method for set interval in AdView without any Timers or Threads?

Comment: This could be changed from the AdMob website as well. See [the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345266/from-where-can-i-change-refresh-rate-for-app-already-in-app-store).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using AdMob, when you set up a specific advertisement, it gives you the option to select a refresh rate. If you already set up an AdMob unit, go to Monetize and click on the ad to edit it.