# From where can I change refresh rate for app already in App Store?

Tags: android, ios, admob

I have an app in the iPhone and Android app stores. They have both banner and interstitial ads.

I remember setting the refresh rate once when setting them up but now I can't find it. I checked my admin account but can't find where I can change it.

Where can I find this setting in the AdMob site?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546318/admob-changing-ads
hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Check it after logging in to your AdMob account:

[image: changing refresh rate, AdMob screenshot]

Comment: but these instructions look like when I am creating a new app. I want to change the refresh rate for an existing app which already had admit integrated into it and on the app store