# Updating Native Ads for Android App

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I have updated my native ad unit. Earlier there was a refresh on 60 Seconds but now, there will be no refresh. I opened my existing ad unit and just checked the **No refresh** box and saved the changes. What should I do to make this change effective ? Will it be propagated automatically or I have to do something as my app is already in the play store?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It will take some time for changes to be deployed (<1 hour) but you do not need to uppload a new version of your app when you change ads settings using admob.
May be useful to read: [From where can I change refresh rate for app already in App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345266/from-where-can-i-change-refresh-rate-for-app-already-in-app-store?rq=1)